# Background image Sass, Css and Express

Tags: css, reactjs, express, sass

Why when i do thi snippest in my .scss:

```
.section-home{
 background-image: url(Yggdrasil.jpg);
 position: relative;
 min-height: 100vh;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

and i run the command yarn watch, in the relative file .css i have this code:

```
.section-home {
  background-image: url(/images/Yggdrasil.jpg?71322804ce7f3cec49ab9190e347b8a6);
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is please.

Comment: why in the css change the path and the image doesn't see?

Comment: Where is the image held in relation to the code file? And how are  you serving the code?

Comment: The image isin the same folder of the .scss and when i run yarn watch, it will create a folder image with the image and in the css file the name follow by ?.....

Comment: In the webpack.mix.js, i have this line of code: mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js').sass('resources/scss/app.scss', 'public/css/app.css');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it. In the file webpack.mix.js i add this line of code:

```
mix.sass('resources/scss/app.scss', 'public/css/app.css').options({
    processCssUrls: false
});
```

because i use laravel-mix. Follow this [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#url-processing)